# How to do exhaustive type guards in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's have TS types defined like this:

```
interface Result<T, E> {
  isOk(): this is Ok<T>;
  isErr(): this is Err<E>;
}

interface Ok<T> extends Result<T, never> {
  value: T;
  isOk(): true;
  isErr(): false;
}

interface Err<E> extends Result<never, E> {
  error: E;
  isOk(): false;
  isErr(): true;
}
```

This is nice because the `Result` interface prescribes the structure of a `Ok` and `Err`. However, when I do a check like this:

```
if (result.isOk()) {
  // A
}

// B
```

In the B part the type of `result` is still `Result` not `Err`. To achieve this, I need to define the types differently:

```
interface Ok<T> {
  value: T;
  isOk(): true;
}

interface Err<E> {
  error: T;
  isOk(): false;
}

type Result<T, E> = Ok<T> | Err<E>;
```

This solved the problem. But now neither `Ok` or `Err` are of type `Result` and I do not have one common interface that says what methods `Ok` and `Err` should both inherit.

My question: is there a way to combine the advantages of both these solutions? To have exhaustive type guards and also to have a common interface which both `Ok` and `Err` extend?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we8ZEW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Or you could use a library neverthrow https://github.com/supermacro/neverthrow